# Xamarin MacOS app launch at login

Tags: xamarin, authentication, startup, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to make my Xamarin MacOS App to run at login. Looking around I found only very old topics with no solutions.

Is there any solution available? Is feasible?

My App runs, by default with Administrator Privileges

Thanks

Comment: "run at startup"... Do you mean as a daemon/service during macOS boot or as a user "Login Item"

Comment: as user logs in! Like "Google Drive", "Skype" and other apps in the status bar!

Comment: So you want to add it to the "Login Item" list, is this a sandboxed app or an ad-hoc app? And which macOS versions are you supporting? And yes, there *are* different ways to handle each scenario

Comment: OS MacOs HighSierra+, the App is ad-hoc, ruquires elevated privileges 'cause it's an "installer / launcher" of other apps (remotely configured)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote this article some time ago. It should still be valid https://shamsutdinov.net/2016/09/27/how-to-launch-at-login-your-xamarin-mac-sandboxed-application/

tl;dr;

Your app should run in the sandbox:
[image: sandboxed app]
In your main app add this code

```
public class StartAtLoginOption
{
    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/ServiceManagement.framework/ServiceManagement")]
    static extern bool SMLoginItemSetEnabled(IntPtr aId, bool aEnabled);


    public static bool StartAtLogin(bool value)
    {
        CoreFoundation.CFString id = new CoreFoundation.CFString("my.helper.app.bundle.id");
        return SMLoginItemSetEnabled(id.Handle, value);
    }
}
```

Create a helper app which only runs in background:
[image: backgroung app]

Start your main app from the helper app:

```
public override void DidFinishLaunching(NSNotification notification)
{
    if (!NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.RunningApplications.Any(a => a.BundleIdentifier == "my.main.app.bundle.id"))
    {
        var path = new NSString(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath)
            .DeleteLastPathComponent()
            .DeleteLastPathComponent()
            .DeleteLastPathComponent()
            .DeleteLastPathComponent();
        var pathToExecutable = path + @"Contents/MacOS/LoginItemTestMain";

        if (NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.LaunchApplication(pathToExecutable)) { }
        else NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.LaunchApplication(path);
    }

    NSApplication.SharedApplication.Terminate(this);

}
```

Comment: Is the Sandbox usage mandatory? I don't think I'll distribute the app as Sandboxed! Thanks

Comment: @ZibaLeah what stops you from marking your app as sandboxed?

Comment: we're working with remote ruby script that installs other tools in the system... I fear that if I sandbox the App I won't be able to install this tools

Comment: Installation is still just copying files to `/Applications` or `~/Applications`. Sandbox is responsible for how the app is run not how it is installed.

Comment: The result is always false, I verified helperBundleIdentifer. What could be the case? How to debug it? `var result = SMLoginItemSetEnabled(id.Handle, value);`

Comment: Unfortunately I never got this to work, I kept getting errors from the App Store: ITMS-90296: App sandbox not enabled - The following executables must include the "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value of true in the entitlements property list: [( "com.myapp.pkg/Payload/MyApp.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/MyAppLoginHelper.app/Contents/MacOS/MyAppLoginHelper" )]

Answer (score 0):

This method works also for "non sandboxed" apps. I don't really like it but, for the moment, it's working:

```
public void SetAtLogin()
    {
        //Checking if the app is in the login items or not
        var script = "tell application \"System Events\"\n get the name of every login item\n if login item \"AppNameTest\" exists then\n return true\n else\n return false\n end if\n end tell";
        NSAppleScript appleScript = new NSAppleScript(script);
        var errors = new NSDictionary();
        NSAppleEventDescriptor result = appleScript.ExecuteAndReturnError(out errors);
        var isLoginItem = result.BooleanValue;

        if (!isLoginItem)
        {
            NSAppleScript login;
            //AppleScript to add app to login items
            script = "tell application \"System Events\"\n make new login item at end of login items with properties {name: \"AppNameTest\", path:\"/Applications/DayOne.app\", hidden:false}\n end tell";
            login = new NSAppleScript(script);
            var resul = login.ExecuteAndReturnError(out errors);
        }
    }
```